# Cocos2dx InApp Purchase for ios

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x

I am trying to integrate In App Purchases in my app made by using cocos2d x c++. I am using easyNdk Helper for In App Purchases. My In App Purchases works perfectly for my Objective C apps. But for cocos2d x it is throwing error for the following line

```
if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:productP.productIdentifier])
```

Actually value came from CPP file perfectly in form of arguments and Properly shows their value in NSLog , But it always shows the objects as nil even objetcs print their stored value in NSLog

also @try catch condition is not working

and finally throw the following error [image]

Please Help me what i have to do ? 
Thanks

my .CPP code is

```
 NDKHelper::AddSelector("HelloWorldSelectors",
                           "SampleSelector",
                           callfuncND_selector(Main::cameFromObjC),
                           this);

            CCDictionary* prms = CCDictionary::create();
            prms->setObject(CCString::create("SampleSelector"), "to_be_called");
            prms->setObject(CCString::create(result), "BirdNameKey");
SendMessageWithParams(string("SampleSelector"), prms);
```

and .mm code is

```
- (void) SampleSelector:(NSObject *)prms
{
    NSLog(@"purchase something called");
    NSDictionary *parameters =   [[NSDictionary alloc]init];// (NSDictionary*)prms;
    parameters = (NSDictionary*)prms;
    NSLog(@"Passed params are : %@", parameters);

    // Fetching the name of the method to be called from Native to C++
    // For a ease of use, i have passed the name of method from C++
    NSString* CPPFunctionToBeCalled = (NSString*)[parameters objectForKey:@"to_be_called"];
    //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[parameters valueForKey:@"BirdNameKey"]];
    NSString *BirdName =  [parameters valueForKey:@"BirdNameKey"];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[parameters objectForKey:@"BirdNameKey"]];
    NSUserDefaults *d2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"%@ , %@ , %@", str,BirdName,[d2 objectForKey:@"product"]); // output is ok for all
    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [ APPDELEGATE.productDictionary objectForKey:[d2 objectForKey:@"product"]];
    [ APPDELEGATE.priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    APPDELEGATE.currentProduct =product;

if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier])
        {
           // check the product purchased or not but app crash at this if statement
        }
   [IOSNDKHelper SendMessage:CPPFunctionToBeCalled WithParameters:nil];
}
```

Comment: This value that you sending to this MM file, is it char*? Also, have you logged this value in the MM file? Plus, what is the retaincount of this object that you are using?

Comment: @Al-mo hi dear , I am passing argument as a CCDictionary from .cpp file to .mm file and then convert it to NSDictionary I didn't use any retain keyword in my project as it is ARC project. I am afraid I din't now where I have to set retaincount :( , I didn't know what do you mean by  "have you logged this value in the MM file" I also tried to set the value by using CCUserDefault and then tried to fetech by NSUserDefault but same problem exists :(

Comment: Before sending this, can you please check what is the RETAINCOUNT of your dictionary, and also, when you are receiving this dictionary, are you accepting it as a NSDICTIONARY(parameter) or are you creating an NSDictionary object using the Dictory you have sent from CPP file?

Comment: Also, make sure you have retained this dictionary before passing it on. It may be that it gets auto released when you try to access it. I need to see the code to understand better.

Comment: @Al-mo I have included the code in my question you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have had this problem and I have resolved it.
in your IAPhelper.mm

Only do this Replace this line

```
_purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
```

with the following line

```
_purchasedProductIdentifiers = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
```

as shown below

```
 - (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        // Store product identifiers
        _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

        // Check for previously purchased products
//        _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
        _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
        for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
            BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
            if (productPurchased) {
                [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
                // NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            } else {
                // NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            }
        }

        // Add self as transaction observer
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    }
    return self;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two (potential) issues with your code,

Firstly

```
CCDictionary* prms = CCDictionary::create();
```

Please note that by initializing a data object this way doesn't guarantee that it will not be released when you try to access it later in the code (specifically in other functions)

So, try this instead,

```
CCDictionary* prms = new CCDictionary();
prms->init ... (the initialization)
```

But please note that by doing it, it is now your responsibility to delete this object once you are done with it. Also, I am not sure about the implementation of "setObject" method, if it is retaining the object then I believe this step won't be necessary, but I'm not sure so you have to check it!

Secondly

```
NSDictionary *parameters =   [[NSDictionary alloc]init];// (NSDictionary*)prms;
parameters = (NSDictionary*)prms;
NSLog(@"Passed params are : %@", parameters);
```

I think there is problem in that casting (or I may be wrong)

I suggest you do something like this

```
(NSDictionary *)nsDictionaryFromCCDictionary:(cocos2d::CCDictionary *)ccDictionary {
if (ccDictionary == NULL) {
    return NULL;
} else if (ccDictionary->allKeys() == NULL) {
    return NULL;
} else if (ccDictionary->allKeys()->count() <= 0) {
    return NULL;
}

cocos2d::CCLog("1");

NSMutableDictionary *nsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:ccDictionary->allKeys()->count()];

cocos2d::CCLog("2");

for (int i = 0; i < ccDictionary->allKeys()->count(); i++) {
    cocos2d::CCLog("3");

    cocos2d::CCObject* obj = ccDictionary->objectForKey(((cocos2d::CCString *)ccDictionary->allKeys()->objectAtIndex(i))->getCString());
    NSObject* nsObject;
    if(isKindOfClass(obj, cocos2d::CCDictionary))
    {
        nsObject = @"Dictionary";
    }
    else if(isKindOfClass(obj, cocos2d::CCArray))
    {
        nsObject = @"Array";
    }
    else if (isKindOfClass(obj, cocos2d::CCString))
    {
        const char* cstring = ((cocos2d::CCString*)obj)->getCString();
        nsObject = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:cstring length:strlen(cstring) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    }
    else if (isKindOfClass(obj, cocos2d::CCInteger))
    {
        nsObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ((cocos2d::CCInteger*)obj)->getValue()];
    }
    else
    {
        nsObject = @"Unknown Object";
    }
    [nsDict setValue:nsObject forKey:[AnalyticXStringUtil nsstringFromCString:((cocos2d::CCString *)ccDictionary->allKeys()->objectAtIndex(i))->getCString()]];
}

return nsDict;
```

}

I have pasted the code above from >>> https://github.com/diwu/AnalyticX/blob/master/Add-To-Your-Own-Project/AnalyticXStringUtil.mm

Try receiving the dictionary as CCDictionary and check if this object is valid (since mm can have c++ and objective c code, so this won't be an issue) Then after creating the NSDictionary, try printing it. I hope it doesn't give you errors this time.

Comment: Dear Al-mo I have tried your suggested techniques but in vain. Even I provide HardCoded In App purchase key but still it is throwing the same error I think it might be some compiler issue

Comment: I would love to debug it...as it seems odd!

Comment: can you provide me any sample ios In App Purchase code running in cocos2d-x